# How can I determine what code Access is using when I apply filters (like 'This Week')? 'Save as Query' is disabled

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table with 2 date fields, IN and OUT.  I want to filter OUT = "Null" and IN = 'This Week"

This is super easy by using Access's built-in drop-down filtering options from the column headers.

BUT I want to use this in VBA.

Rather than writing my own code (using datepart or datediff) I want to 'Save' the filter I have created manually and use it when I open/update the table.

Can I view the filter code Access is using?  Or can I apply the 'This Week' filter in VBA in a way similar to DoCmd.applyFilter , ([IN] is "This Week")

Surely I can apply access's built-in filters instead of creating a custom filter??